# Two (apparently) identical strings give different results when run as a terminal command

Tags: c, string, awk, string-concatenation

I'm using `popen()` in C to run a Linux command which is built as a `char` through many steps during the program.

I have a header file for the MESS struct:

```c
typedef struct{ 
    char date[50];
    char time1[50];
    char time2[50];
} MESS;
```

And the main program receives a `mess` from another program containing strings in the format of date - `11.16.`, time1 - `11:03`, time2- `15:46`:

```c
const char *months[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

// ...
MESS mess;
FILE *fp;
char command[256];

// ...
// receiving mess using msgrcv()
// ...

strcpy(command, "last -f ./entries | grep -E '");

//concatenate the corresponding month as a String using the months[] array
char date[3];
strncpy(date, mess.date, 2);
date[2] = '\0';
strcat(command, months[atoi(date)-1]);

//concatenate the day of the month
strcat(command, " ");
strncpy(date, mess.date+3, 2);
strcat(command, date);

//returns first columns (entry names) of entry lines where the time corresponds to the given interval
// strcat(command, "' | awk '$0 ~ /.*[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].*/ { p=0; if ($7 >= \"");
// strcat(command, mess.time1);
// strcat(command, "\" ) p=1; if ($7 >= \"");
// strcat(command, mess.time2);
// strcat(command, "\" ) p=0; } p { print $1 }'");

//same as above, but
//hard-coding the time values 11:03 and 15:46
//instead of obtaining them from mess
strcat(command, "' | awk '$0 ~ /.*[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].*/ { p=0; if ($7 >= \"11:03\" ) p=1; if ($7 >= \"15:46\" ) p=0; } p { print $1 }'");

printf("%s\n\n", command);

//execute the command
fp = NULL;
fp = popen(command, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("Error opening fp\n");
    exit(1);
}

char result[10];
while (fgets(result, 10, fp) != NULL){
            printf("%s", result);
    }
pclose(fp);
```

Executing the above code will give me the desired results:

```
$ ./program
last -f ./entries | grep -E 'Nov 16' | awk '$0 ~ /.*[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].*/ { p=0; if ($7 >= "11:03" ) p=1; if ($7 >= "15:46" ) p=0; } p { print $1 }'

entry354

entry398

entry503

entry637

entry684

entry721
```

However, if I comment the hard-coded `strcat()` line and uncomment the other five lines before it, the program will print the same string, but the command won't produce any result.

```
$ ./server
last -f ./entries | grep -E 'Nov 16' | awk '$0 ~ /.*[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].*/ { p=0; if ($7 >= "11:03" ) p=1; if ($7 >= "15:46" ) p=0; } p { print $1 }'
```

The two are apparently the same, yet they won't give the same result. Why won't the one where I build it step by step work despite the strings being the same?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. We can't tell what `mess.time1` and `mess.time2` are. Please [edit] your question to include a complete set of code, sample input and output, and any error messages. This will help us answer your question better.

Comment: Try to save the command you build to a file (even w/o running it), using the first method and then the second method, and  compare two files with `diff`. Probably they are not similar after all

Comment: I included a header file, this tells us what `mess` is.

Comment: That `strncpy()` looks really suspicious.

Comment: That seems to be working in my code, and up to that point the command given by the string is also producing the desired results, it returns entries from Nov 16.

Comment: And your code can be simplified a lot by using one `snprintf()` instead of all those `strcat()`'s.

Comment: The header file isn't sufficient. See the [mre] link for details on what's needed.

Comment: Why not try the same with a much simpler script and try to debug THAT? e.g. start by replacing `awk '$0 ~ /.*[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].*/ { p=0; if ($7 >= "11:03" ) p=1; if ($7 >= "15:46" ) p=0; } p { print $1 }'` with `cat`. If that works then try `awk '1'`. If that works... and so on til you identify the point of failure.

Comment: What do you mean with _The two are apparently the same,...?_  Are they the same or different? have you checked?

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  as most probably the problem is in some part of the code you have eliminated in your snippet.  Prepare a minimal code that can be compiled (that you have run locally showing the problem) and post that code, don't touch it to post as you change the code and you can eliminate it from the program.